# Web Notification API - website doesn't need to be open?

Tags: javascript, html, web-notifications

I noticed some news sites such as Washington Post are able to pop up Web Notifications even though I don't have the site open in a tab. I don't recall this being possible before. How is it even possible for a website to execute the JS necessary if the site isn't open? How does one accomplish this using Web Notifications, is there a particular setting to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe it's you mean this https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe they are using Push Notifications via [Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers).

You can check the [current support status](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) to see if it's fit for you. It's well supported in modern browsers (although perhaps not the full specification).

> A service worker is a script that your browser runs in the background,
>   separate from a web page, opening the door to features that don't need
>   a web page or user interaction. Today, they already include features
>   like push notifications and background sync.

and

> A service worker has a lifecycle that is completely separate from your
>   web page.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I would've never found what this was called.